# How to read currently connected monitor(s) IDs?

Tags: c++, c, windows

In registry there is a key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\{VESA_Monitor_ID}\{PnP_ID}\Device Parmeters\EDID
```

I want to know, if there is a way to get the {VESA_Monitor_ID} and {PnP_ID}? Is there an API for this, or can i do this somehow using C or C++?

Thanks!

Comment: a quick google showed up many sites that handle registry access via winapi...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: i know that, but then i won't know which monitor is connected and which isn't. If there is a Pc where was 5 monitors attachad earlier, but now it is a 6th one, then if i read the registry, i won't know which one is currently connected

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`EnumMonitors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`EnumDisplayDevices()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetupDiGetClassDevs()`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259695).

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from the [Win32_DesktopMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Class.

Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx

Just replace Win32_OperatingSystem in the query from the example.